# NFS lock-up over 1Gb ethernet: Post 14.04.5 to Zyxel NSA325 v2

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, networking, nfs, nas

When mounting a NFS share over 1000Mbps Ethernet connection, a cp or rsync will lock up after a few MBytes transferred. This does NOT occur when using earlier Ubuntu versions / derivatives.

**NAS server:**  Zyxel NSA325 v2, V4.81(AALS.1)

**Clients which lock up:**

- Linux Mint 17.1, 17.2, 17.3, 18.1, 18.2 (x64 & 32-bit)
- Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.2
- Laptops and desktops connect via GB Ethernet

**Clients which do NOT lock up:**

- Ubuntu Studio 14.04.5 LTS 

  ($ uname -a 
  Linux HP-Z600 3.13.0-117-lowlatency #164-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 7 11:41:01 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
- Linux Mint 18.2 32-bit over 54Mbps WiFi

*Is this a NFS regression introduced in Ubuntu/Debian at Ubuntu 16.04?*

This is forcing me to use CIFS/Samba shares which are slower and don't map permissions with ext4 file systems.

**EDIT:** 
Mounts are usually on command line, not fstab:

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=3 192.168.1.nnn:/internal_path/nfs/NAS /mnt/nas-nfs
```

I've tried both with and without the `-o nfsvers=3`

Comment: i have no issues with any NFS server or client, but don't have your NAS box. I'd be tempted to blame your NAS or a router/switch on your network. Try a smaller block size (rsize,wsize..) but mint 17.x is 14.04LTS anyway

Comment: Right, just re-tested LM17.3 with GB Enet. **Locked up after 78MB**. $ uname -a
Linux HP-Z600 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @guiverc, thanks. Same HW works with Ubuntu Studio 14.04.5. I'll try the smaller block sizes.

Comment: @guiverc: I set wsize=32768. LM17.3 worked. Now for the others!! THANKS

Comment: Looks like the NSA325 v2 can't handle `wsize=65536` but *can handle* `$ sudo mount -t nfs -o wsize=32768`

Comment: Also: NSA325 is configured with 9K Jumbo Frames enabled. This may also be a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @guiverc for the `wsize=` tip!

Apparently the Zyxel NSA325 v2 cannot handle NFS write block sizes greater than 32K. Using the `wsize=32768` option when mounting the NFS share, the following are able to write multiple GBytes to the NAS over 1Gbps Ethernet at >40MB/s:

- Linux Mint 17.3 x64
- Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.2 x64
- Linux Mint 18.2 x64

The 54Mbps WiFi would not be capable of exceeding the speeds and block sizes on which the NAS chokes. Apparently my Ubuntu Studio 14.04 does not have the Gigabit Ethernet configured to allow large window / block sizes sufficient to flood the NAS as well.

Now, for mapping local UID/GID values to NAS values on NFS mounts...